# Highest version of ubuntu for Sun Fire V100 (UltraSPARC-IIe 648MHz)

Tags: versions

I'm currently running ubuntu 7.10 on a Sun Fire V100 (UltraSPARC-IIe 648MHz). What is the highest version supported? Can I upgrade to that version directly from 7.10 and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to do a fresh install since support for 7.10 has been dropped in 2009. 
 You could try to install 8.04 from an old ubuntu mirror it was a pretty awesome very stable build. 
 However support has ended for it as well (meaning no new updates etc.) and your processor doesn't meet the minimum system requirements I believe.
 You can download it from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/8.04/)

As for newer ubuntu versions I would say you aren't able to run them on that hardware. 
You should look into **damnsmalllinux** or **puppy linux** if you want new kernel features.